# How to locate an element based on its text?

Tags: css-selectors, cypress, ui-automation

This is the DOM for the elements,

```html
<span _ngcontent-vej-c357="" class="tree-oooo-name mr-2 mod-cursor-pointer"> 
  qa-testData1 
  <span _ngcontent-vej-c357="" class="some-name"><!----></span>
</span>

<span _ngcontent-vej-c357="" class="tree-oooo-name mr-2 mod-cursor-pointer"> 
  qa-testData2 
  <span _ngcontent-vej-c357="" class="some-name"><!----></span>
</span>
```

Note: In the DOM, there are more than 10 elements with same identifier - `tree-oooo-name mr-2 mod-cursor-pointer`

When I try to use this selector it gives more than 1 matching element:
`span[class*='tree-oooo-name']`

Is there a way to identify the element based on its name (`qa-testData1` and `qa-testData2`) without using xpath?

Comment: "tree-oooo-name mr-2 mod-cursor-pointer" is not a name is a CSS class add id or name attribute to be identifiable/unique.

Answer (score 2):

Text such as `qa-testData1` can be used in the selector with `:contains()`,

```js
cy.get('span[class*="tree-oooo-name"]:contains(qa-testData1)')
```

or use the `.contains()` query chained after the `cy.get()`.

```js
cy.get('span[class*="tree-oooo-name"]').contains('qa-testData1')
```

but you may have some trouble with this particular HTML as there seems to be a textNode followed by another `<span>` without the previous one being closed.

Cypress is very fussy about the HTML being correctly formed.

Answer (score 0):

To locate a web element based on its **name** in Cypress, you can use either the name attribute selector or the **contains** method.

Using the **name** attribute selector:

```
cy.get('[name="username"]')
```

This code locates the element with the **name** attribute set to "username". You can replace "username" with the actual name of the element you want to locate.

Using the **contains** method:

```
cy.contains('[name]', 'username')
```

This code locates the element that has a **name** attribute and contains the text "username". Again, you can replace "username" with the actual name of the element you want to locate.

Both methods return a Cypress object that represents the web element, which you can use to interact with the element.

**NOTE**: You can locate a web element using the cy.get() method with various selector options, such as the element's tag name, class name, ID, attribute, etc.